# Grails error Null Pointer Exception accesses GSP

Tags: rest, grails, groovy, gsp

Hey Guys: I am really stuck on this one.

I have a grails app that is using a REST service.
It works fine for accessing the REST service, but the issue is when I want to render the results in a GSP. I get the following error:

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /TestAPI/login/index
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here are my issues:
1. I am trying to send the output to a different GSP and not index.
2. I read the stack trace and in my project, I have index.gsp in that path that it says it can't find.

Here is my controller code:

```
package testapi

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
import org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import groovyx.net.http.*

import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;


//import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

class LoginController {

    def index() 
    { 
        String usernm = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        String link = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/oauth2/token";
        String passwd = "yyyyyy";
        //Base64.encodeBase64(usernm.concat(":".concat(passwd)).getBytes())
        Base64.getEncoder().encode(usernm.concat(":".concat(passwd)).getBytes());
        String base64UserCreds = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(usernm.concat(":".concat(passwd)).getBytes()));

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Authorization","Basic ".concat(base64UserCreds));

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

        System.out.println ("URI under Test is: " + String.valueOf(link) + ". \n" + "Please stand by for results ... \n \n ");
        System.out.println ("Base 64 encoded string is: " + base64UserCreds);

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map result = restTemplate.exchange(link, HttpMethod.POST, request, Map.class).getBody();

        String authtype = (String) result.get("tokenType");
        String tokenaccess = (String) result.get("accessToken");
        //PrintStream testOutput = null;
        //testOutput.append(result2);
        System.out.println("Access token: " + tokenaccess + "\n");

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders2 = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders2.add("zzzz-pppp-oauth-scope", "zzz:read-any");
        requestHeaders2.add("Authorization","Bearer ".concat(tokenaccess));
        HttpEntity<String> request2 = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders2);
        System.out.println("URI #1 under test: https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx?expand=reps \n");
        String result3 = restTemplate.exchange("https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx?expand=reps", HttpMethod.GET, request2, String.class).getBody();
        [result3]
        render(view: "api_test", model:[name: result3])
        System.out.println(result3);

    }
}
```

And here is the gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>AutoTest - API</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">

  API Results ${result3}

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I do not have a domain class file; Do I need one if so - please advise me how to structure it.

Thanks.

NOTE: adding a picture of the directory structure of the project:

[image: grails project directory structure]

Comment: Tried `API Results ${name}`?

Comment: @tim_yates it throws the sam error.

Comment: @ironmantis7x you don't need a domain class to get controller to display gsp. Tim's suggestion should work.  I would suggest stopping starting app the variable in model is name: result3   so this should be ${name}

Comment: @vahid I don't fully understand your statement. can you please make it more clear what you are explaining? do i put in the controller "render(view: "api_test", model:[name: ${name])" ?

Comment: You are passing `result3` under `name` key to GSP, so in your GSP you should have `API Results ${result3}` replaced by `API Results ${name}`. But still this should not cause NPE. Are you showing whole Stacktrace as it doesnt look like the whole one?

Comment: @droggo thanks. and yes - that was the whole stack trace I got (unless I am missing something)

Comment: when I make the change in the GSP with the same controller, I still get a NPE. 
When I change the render line in the controller to: "render result3", I get the results in the index page (not where I want it) as just raw JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

render result3 will not render a view but the content of result3, so the json response is not weird.

if you could post your filenames with directories from 'grails-app' we might see the problem (e.g. '/grails-app/views/login/api_test.gsp')

Comment: <img src="/Users/ironmantis7x/Desktop/grailsscreenshot.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: how do I upload an image? I took a screenshot of my project directory

Comment: I added a picture with the directory file structure

Comment: api_test.gsp is not in the login folder

Comment: sometimes -- it's the tree right in front of your face that you just don't see ... "dooh!!" LOL!! 
This is the correct solution.